# Generate pre-signed url of private Image and load to a image view - S3 Client android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to load image from my S3 Bucket in my android application. My images are private so I won't be having any specific link for each image.

I'm using link generator,

```
s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, expiration);
```

It generates a URL with let's say 1 hour or 2 min expiration.

Now I have problem in loading the url. I tried loading it by using picasso ,

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url.toString()).resize(30,38).into(holder.photo);
```

but it's not quite seems to be working. When I tried that link on browser I got following error

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach error listener to Picasso and see what's going on. Also read logcat. Print URL which you pass to Picasso, does it correct?

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso arg0, String err) {
            Log.e("Picasso Error", "Errored " + err);

        }
    });

    builder.loggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso pic = builder.build();
    pic.load("image.jpg").into(iv);
```

Comment: Ok, hold on . .I will try that out now

Comment: stacktrace says "ResponseException: 404 Not Found"

Comment: I think problem in URl itself or how you generate it.